# Why does this not work? "d is not defined"

Tags: python, undefined

I'm currently doing python for recreational uses and this ATM script is not running correctly, please help.

```
def balance():
    balance=7.52
    return balance
    print("Hi, Welcome to the Atm.")
    print("no need for pin numbers, we already know who you are")
    print("please selection one of the options given beneath")
    print("""
            D = Deposit
            W = Withdrawal
            T = Transfer
            B = Balance check
            Q = Quick cash of 20$
            E = Exit
            Please select in the next line.""")

def option():
    option = input("which option would you like?:")
    return option
    input("which option would you like?:")
    if option == "D":
        print("How much would you like to deposit?")
        amount = (int(input("amount:")))
        total = amount + balance
```

Comment: Something horrible happened to your code's indentation. Please fix it.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow.

This code won’t work at all, as it is not indented correctly. Please provide a working code example and more detailed information about the error. Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you are using Python 2, in which [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input) attempts to evaluate what the user types as though it were a Python statement.  You should instead use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input), which does not.

Answer (score 0):

When the script ask you "which option would you like?:" you have to type "D" or 'D' and not D cause the input function, I think you should use [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input)

And you will have an other problem with the line:

```
total=amount+balance
```

you have to add () for call function

```
total=amount+balance()
```

And with this line:

```
if option =="D":
```

Cause option is not define.

```
option = option()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def balance():
    balance=7.52
    return balance
    print("Hi, Welcome to the Atm.")
    print("no need for pin numbers, we already know who you are")
    print("please selection one of the options given beneath")
    print("""
    D = Deposit
    W = Withdrawal
    T = Transfer
    B = Balance check
    Q = Quick cash of 20$
    E = Exit
    Please select in the next line.   """)
def option():
    option=input("which option would you like?:")
    return option
    input("which option would you like?:")
    if option =="D":
        print("How much would you like to deposit?")
        amount=(int(input("amount:")))
        total=amount+balance
```

You will need to indent your code ***correctly*** so it looks like this (look up):
`input` is only used in Python 3.x. The equivalent of the Python 3.x version is `raw_input`, the Python 2.x version. Using the same name for a variable and function is not recommended, due to the confusion to come. It is better to rename one of them. If you are using Python 3.x, then you need to fix your indention. Try the [Python 2.7 Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/) or the [Python 3.x Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/)